# Fraction Cross Multiply

Tags: fractions, mathematica

Students first learning about fractions are often taught to "cross-multiply" when dealing with fraction with non-like denominators, however, in Mathematica, with the function `SameQ`: $$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b} = \frac{ay+xb}{yb}$$ returns "False," which seems to indicate that cross multiplying does not work universally. Am I doing something wrong here?

(The function `SameQ` prints "True" if the equations on the left and right side are identical and returns "false" if they are not.)

Comment: I misunderstood the question and delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica checks that your equation is true for *all* $x$, $y$, $a$ and $b$ that are in the real numbers (I suppose, you should verify that with your Mathematica documentation).

Indeed,

$$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b} \ne \frac{ay+xb}{yb}$$

when $y = 0$ or $b=0$.

---

Added:
It might interest you to know precisely from where comes the equation.

We first define $\frac{1}{x}$, as being the inverse element of $x$, denoted $x^{-1}$. This is the element $x^{-1}$ such that $x\cdot x^{-1} = 1$ . *This element only exists if $x\ne 0$, because if otherwise, then $x\cdot x^{-1} = 0 \cdot x^{-1} = 0 \ne 1$ which is a contradiction.*

If $x, y, a, b \in \mathbb{R}$,  $y \ne 0$ and $x \ne 0$, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b} &= \left ( \frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b} \right ) \cdot 1\\
&=\left ( \frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b} \right ) \cdot \frac{yb}{yb}\\
&=\left ( \frac{x}{y}\cdot yb +\frac{a}{b}\cdot yb \right ) \cdot \frac{1}{yb}\\
&=\left ( xb +ay \right ) \cdot \frac{1}{yb}\\
&=\frac{xb +ay}{yb}
\end{align}

Note that this follows from the assumption that $y \ne 0$ and $x \ne 0$.

Comment: That's interesting because y=0 and b=0 are not allowed on *both* sides, so both sides should still be equal

Comment: If $y=0$ but $x\ne 0$, (or otherwise) then the equation would still be false, which is sufficient to say that the equation is not true for all natural numbers.

Comment: Also, the number $1/x$ only exists (in the reals, at least) if $x$ is non-zero. You cannot deduce anything from numbers that do not exists, so you cannot say that the equation is true when both $x$ and $y$ are zero.

Comment: Yes, but one may think that Mathematica would check for the functions domains. What happens if you ask if $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}$ ?

Comment: Excatly what I meant: actually if you consider both sides as functions, they are the same (and thus equal), because both y and b do not belong to the domain in both cases.

Comment: @Olivier: if $y=0$ neither side is defined. So the equation is neither true nor false.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) reports the following:

["TrueQ[x/y+a/b=(ay+xb)/(yb)]": False](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=TrueQ%5Bx/y%2ba/b=%28ay%2bxb%29/%28yb%29%5D)

["Is x/y+a/b=(ay+xb)/(yb)?": True](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is%20x/y%2ba/b=%28ay%2bxb%29/%28yb%29?)

Which is rather strange. And it doesn't help to make those denominators non-zero, by replacing them with $1+y^2$ and $1+b^2$:

["TrueQ[x/(1+y^2)+a/(1+b^2)=(a(1+y^2)+x(1+b^2))/((1+y^2)(1+b^2))]": False](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=TrueQ%5Bx/%281%2by%5E2%29%2ba/%281%2bb%5E2%29=%28a%281%2by%5E2%29%2bx%281%2bb%5E2%29%29/%28%281%2by%5E2%29%281%2bb%5E2%29%29%5D)

["Is x/(1+y^2)+a/(1+b^2)=(a(1+y^2)+x(1+b^2))/((1+y^2)(1+b^2))?": True](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Is%20x/%281%2by%5E2%29%2ba/%281%2bb%5E2%29=%28a%281%2by%5E2%29%2bx%281%2bb%5E2%29%29/%28%281%2by%5E2%29%281%2bb%5E2%29%29?)